# Display all x-axis labels on ggplot histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, tidyverse, histogram

I have a simple frequency histogram for a data with 65k rows and here is the code I have with an example data:

```
data <- data.frame(var1=floor(6*rnorm(65000)  + 1))
data %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=var1)) +
    geom_histogram(fill="lightblue", color="black", alpha=0.9, bins = 30) +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(size=15),
          axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5)) +
    stat_bin(geom="text", 
           colour="black",
           bins = 30,
           aes(label=..count..), 
           angle = 45, 
           vjust=-.5)
```

The plot has 30 bins but has 3 labels on x - axis:

[image]

I just want it to have a label for each bin.

I tried theme() and scale_x_cont() but they did not work and messed the whole plot. I don't want to change anything i just want to add labels on the x. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

A different approach to draw your histogram and at the same time allowing to add axis labels for each bin would be to use `geom_bar` with `scale_x_binned`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(123)

data <- data.frame(var1 = floor(6 * rnorm(200) + 1))

ggplot(data, aes(x = var1)) +
  geom_bar(fill = "lightblue", color = "black", alpha = 0.9) +
  stat_count(
    geom = "text",
    colour = "black",
    aes(label = after_stat(count)),
    angle = 45,
    vjust = 0,
    hjust = 0
  ) +
  scale_x_binned(n.breaks = 30, show.limits = TRUE) +
  theme(
    plot.title = element_text(size = 15),
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = .5)
  )
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One way could be using `scale_x_continuous()` with the `breaks`

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

data <- data.frame(var1 = floor(6 * rnorm(200) + 1))

data %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = var1)) +
  geom_histogram(fill = "lightblue", color = "black", alpha = 0.9, bins = 30) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 15),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5)) +
  stat_bin(
    geom = "text",
    colour = "black",
    bins = 30,
    aes(label = ..count..),
    angle = 45,
    vjust = -0.5
  ) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(min(data$var1), max(data$var1), by = 1))
```

[image]

Comment: Same result as the solution given by Gregor Thomas. Too many labels and all overlapping.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `scale_x_continuous` to modify how the x axis scale looks. You can change the number of breaks using `n.breaks` or adjust using `breaks` or `labels`. The [documentation](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_continuous.html) gives great detail, and this [book](https://ggplot2-book.org/scales-guides.html) is an awesome resource for understanding scales a bit better (and `ggplot2` as a whole).

For your code, the answer looks like:

```
data %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=var1)) +
    geom_histogram(fill="lightblue", color="black", alpha=0.9, bins = 30) +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(size=15),
          axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5)) +
    stat_bin(geom="text", 
           colour="black",
           bins = 30,
           aes(label=..count..), 
           angle = 45, 
           vjust=-.5) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(-17, 17, 1))
```

I would also add that `..count..` has been deprecated by `ggplot2 3.4.0`. [Here](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/aes_eval.html?q=after_stat#stage-after-stat-transformation) is a little more info about the deprecation and the new approach. To avoid getting a warning, try:

```
data %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=var1)) +
    geom_histogram(fill="lightblue", color="black", alpha=0.9, bins = 30) +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(size=15),
          axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5)) +
    stat_bin(geom="text", 
           colour="black",
           bins = 30,
           aes(label = after_stat(count)), 
           angle = 45, 
           vjust=-.5) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(-17, 17, 1))
```

Comment: This almost solves it, but I have 2 extra labels at the start and end of the x-axis with no values. Why is that?

Comment: I tried this on my real data and this adds the marks on the x-axis but the labels don't align with the bars, so it makes the plot look inaccurate. Does it make sense?

Comment: Yeah makes sense - the reason the labels don't align is because you are using a histogram, so the labels are on either side of the bars rather than under them to indicate the "bins". Histograms work by finding any value where 0 < x < 0.999 for the bin from 0 to 1, and then finding 1 < x < 1.999 for the bin from 1 to 2, etc. You could fix this by replacing `geom_histogram` with `geom_bar` and getting rid of the `bins` argument, but this will result in a different type of analysis

Answer (score 0):

From `?scale_x_continuous`, the `breaks` argument can be one of

> `NULL` for no breaks
>
> `waiver()` for the default breaks computed by the transformation object
>
> A numeric vector of positions
>
> A function that takes the limits as input and returns breaks as output (e.g., a function returned by `scales::extended_breaks()`). Also accepts `rlang` lambda function notation.

Using the last option, we can make a simple function giving every integer in the axis:

```
data <- data.frame(var1=floor(6*rnorm(200)  + 1))
data %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=var1)) +
    geom_histogram(fill="lightblue", color="black", alpha=0.9, bins = 30) +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(size=15),
          axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5)) +
    stat_bin(geom="text", 
           colour="black",
           bins = 30,
           aes(label=..count..), 
           angle = 45, 
           vjust=-.5) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = function(range) floor(range[1]):ceiling(range[2]))
```

[image]

Comment: this doesn't work, there are so many labels and overlapping cannot even read one of them.

Comment: Maybe you want to set the number of labels to be the number of bins. I interpreted *"Display all x-axis labels"* as label each integer on the x-axis, which this does. I see later you say *"have a label for each bin"*. Try using the `n.breaks` argument, or override it looking for nice numbers and use `function(range) seq(range[1], range[2], length.out = n_bins)` where `n_bins` is the number of bins in your histogram (30, in this case). You might want to wrap it in `round()` too...